# git - Pushing a local branch to the remote tracking branch of a parent

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch, git-push

I have a local branch in my sandbox repository called `local-branch` which tracks a remote branch called `remote-branch`. I created the local branch thus:

```
$ git checkout -b local-branch remotes/origin/remote-branch
```

I created a branch from the `local-branch` called `dev-branch`:

```
$ git checkout -b dev-branch local-branch
```

I then committed some changes to `dev-branch` and now want to push it upstream to a branch off `remote-branch`. There it gets reviewed, approved and then merged into `remote-branch`. Following that, I need to `git pull` on my `local-branch` to sync it with `remote-branch`.

I am trying the following but this does not seem to work.

```
$ git push remotes/origin/remote-branch local-branch
```

I see the following error:

```
fatal: 'remotes/origin/remote-branch' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

But I can see the repository when I run:

```
$ git branch -a
```

Comment: Looks like:

`$ git push origin local-branch`

works.

Answer (score 4):

To push `local-branch` from your repository into `remote-branch` on remote `origin`, use

```
git push origin local-branch:remote-branch
```

Based on the way you created `local-branch` in your question, git should have configured it to track `origin/remote-branch`. In that case, a simple `git pull` while `local-branch` is checked out will suffice to sync.

Your workflow is complicated. I suggest looking for ways to simplify that involve fewer names for each given branch.

Comment: The whole `local-branch` is redundant, since it doesn't seem to be used as a working branch. Just creating `dev-branch` from where ever `remote-branch` was pointing is enough. Then just `git push origin dev-branch` when done with the working branch. I'm guessing there's some misunderstanding about what branches mean in Git: branches do not refer to other branches, only commits, which in turn link to their parent commits. There's no link from parent to child. That would require a rewrite of the latest commit on a new commit. Which is the reason why "dangling commits" are bad.